# Codeigniter image resize() thumbnail name issue

Tags: codeigniter, image-resizing

When I resize an image keeping  `$config['create_thumb'] = true` Codeigniter adds the string "_thumb" in the end of the name of resized image.

What I want ask is, is it possible to add the suffix "_thumb" in the beginning of the image name

example:
original_name.jpg

after resizing:
original_name_thumb.jpg

What I want:
thumb_original_name.jpg

Any kind of help is appreciated!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can try this:

```
$data = $this->upload->data();
$config['create_thumb'] = false;
$config['new_image'] = 'thumb_'.$data['file_name'];
```

And if you have other problems with CI image manipulation library, maybe you can try [ImageMoo](http://www.matmoo.com/digital-dribble/codeigniter/image_moo/).

Answer (score 9):

If u don't want to add the suffix _thumb in thumbnail file name then
use `$config['thumb_marker'] = false;`

Answer (score -1):

this can be achieved by following way

> $data = $this->upload->data();
>
> $config['create_thumb'] = false;
>
> $config['new_image'] = 'thumb_'.$data['file_name'];

for more information about re-size image check out following Code.

> function special_resize($oldFile, $width, $height)
>       {
>           $obj =& get_instance();
>
> ```
>     $info = pathinfo($oldFile);        
>     out($info);
>
>     $tempFile = '/public/files/files/temp/' . $info['filename'] . '-' . $width . 'x' . $height . '.' . $info['extension'];
>     $newFile = '/public/files/files/cache/' . $info['filename'] . '-' . $width . 'x' . $height . '.' . $info['extension'];
>
>     //if image already exists, use it
>     if(file_exists('.' .$newFile))
>         return $newFile;
>
>     //math for resize/crop without loss
>     $o_size = _get_size( '/' . $info['dirname'] . '/' . $info['basename']);        
>
>     $master_dim = ($o_size['width']-$width < $o_size['height']-$height?'width':'height');
>
>     $perc = max( (100*$width)/$o_size['width'] , (100*$height)/$o_size['height']  );
>
>     $perc = round($perc, 0);
>
>     $w_d = round(($perc*$o_size['width'])/100, 0);        
>     $h_d = round(($perc*$o_size['height'])/100, 0);
>
>             // end math stuff
>
>     /*
>      *    Resize image
>      */
>     $config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
>     $config['source_image'] = $oldFile;
>     $config['new_image'] = '.' . $tempFile;
>     $config['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
>     $config['master_dim'] = $master_dim;
>     $config['width'] = $w_d + 1;
>     $config['height'] = $h_d + 1;
>
>     $obj->image_lib->initialize($config);
>
>     $obj->image_lib->resize();
>
>     $size = _get_size($tempFile);    
>
>     unset($config); // clear $config
>
>     /*
>      *    Crop image  in weight, height
>      */
>
>     $config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
>     $config['source_image'] = '.' . $tempFile;
>     $config['new_image'] = '.' . $newFile;
>     $config['maintain_ratio'] = FALSE;
>     $config['width'] = $width;
>     $config['height'] = $height;
>     $config['y_axis'] = round(($size['height'] - $height) / 2);
>     $config['x_axis'] = 0;
>
>     $obj->image_lib->clear();
>     $obj->image_lib->initialize($config);
>     if ( ! $obj->image_lib->crop())
>     {
>         echo $obj->image_lib->display_errors();
>     }
>
>     $info = pathinfo($newFile);        
>     out($info);
>
>     return $newFile;
> }
> ```